# Postman application showing error that it couldn't connect to server

Tags: mongodb, postman

When I'm trying to use POST operation through local host server. It is not connecting to the server and showing the following error :
There was an error connecting to http://localhost:4500/api/user/signup.

Please find attached screenshot for the same

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZFft.png)

Answer (score 0):

That means there is no server running on that port. Please check server first whether the port is correct or not.